# How can I combine GitHub build-push-action with running jobs inside that container?

Tags: docker, github-actions

In my workflow I'm building an image without pushing it, using **build-push-action**:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2
        
      - name: Build
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
        with:
          target: node_builder
          tags: node_builder:latest
```

After building, I'd like to **run jobs directly in the container**, like explained in [running jobs in a container](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/running-jobs-in-a-container). For what I understand I need another job named `run`:

```yml
run:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  container: node:14.16
```

But jobs run in isolation, so I've found that one can [share built images between jobs](https://docs.docker.com/build/ci/github-actions/share-image-jobs/):

```yml
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      # ...

      - name: Upload image
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: node_builder
          path: /tmp/node_builder.tar

  run:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Download image
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node_builder
          path: /tmp

      - name: Load image
        run: docker load --input /tmp/node_builder.tar
```

I still can't **understand how to "glue" things togheter**: how to run a job with `container: node_builder:latest` (my image), downloading my built image before?

Comment: What kind of jobs are these that you want to run in this newly built container? Can you not directly run those as scripts in the container itself similar to [Test before push with GitHub Actions](https://docs.docker.com/build/ci/github-actions/test-before-push/) approach?

Comment: Another approach could be to push this built image to [GHCR](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-container-registry) with private visibility and then pull it to run your jobs with `container`.

Comment: @Azeem good idea, but it the image removal easy then? Using the workflow itself

Comment: You may use [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api) to delete the package using the [REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/packages?apiVersion=2022-11-28).